# Is the group of units in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}$ finite and cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be its ring of integers. Consider the group of units in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Is it finite? Is it cyclic?

**My thought:**

For any $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{2}$, its norm is $\mathcal{N}(\alpha)=a^2-2b^2.$ Since an element in $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a unit if and only if its norm is $\pm 1$, we must have $a^2 - 2b^2 = \pm 1$. The equation $a^2 - 2b^2 = 1$ has inifintely many solutions, so the group of units is not finite.

For the cyclic part, suppose $\mathcal{O}_K$ is cyclic then it should have a generator $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal{N}(\alpha)=\pm1$. Let $x,y$ be two units, then $x=\alpha^m$ and $y=\alpha^n$ for some $m,n$. So we have $\alpha^{m+n} = 1$ for some $m,n$. But this implies that the group is finite. A contradiction?

Comment: Try to find a fundamental solution to Pell's equation $a^2-2b^2=1$. Or if you want to use a sledgehammer, look up Dirichlet's units theorem.

Comment: If you already know that $\mathcal O_K$ has infinitely many units, then it cannot be cyclic by an argument very similar to what you gave above: If $\alpha$ was a cyclic generator, there would have to be a $k$ with $\alpha^k = -1$. But then $\alpha^{2k}= 1$, so $\alpha$ generates a finite group, contradicting the fact that there are infinitely many units.

Comment: @user218931 why $a^k = -1$?

Comment: Because $\alpha$ is supposed to be a cyclic generator of the group of units and $-1$ is a unit. In other words: Since the group of units is infinite, assuming that it is cyclic implies that every element has infinite order (except 1), but $-1$ has finite order 2, so this gives a contradiction.